# Switch 12v solenoid from 3v3 control signal

Tags: mosfet, switches, solenoid

I am going in circles on the web and appreciate your help with this novice question, operate a solenoid with a mosfet (original idea, I know). I bought a Gravity DFR0457 to switch a 12V solenoid on from a camera remote (Pocketwizard) that outputs 3v3. I can't get it to work (apparently common with logic level needing more voltage), so i am guessing i have to bump up the output remote 3v3 somehow?. Is this even the correct route to go? I was hoping that I could use existing boards so i wouldn't have to solder together different components.

Schematic for the DFR0457 MOSFET switch module:
[image: Schematic for the DFR0457 MOSFET switch module]

Connection diagram

[image]

My schematic
[image]

Comment: How have you connected things? Show a diagram of what you've tried.

Comment: Please see the many existing questions on doing this that are already here

Comment: I tried it with a 9v battery and it works, just not with the 3v3 remote output.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to supply 12V separately.  An all-in one relay/solenoid driver with a MOSFET, gate resistor, and coil diode in the same package could be soldered to a little breakout board fairly easily.  The NUD3112 could be an attractive option.

Comment: Thank you. Sounds like a good entry level project.